# Extra field is not showing in Django administration user creation form

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework, vs-web-site-project

[image][image][image]
I have written  forms.py and admin.py. but extra field such as email, full name is not showing in Django administration user creation form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked one of my projects and that's how I'm doing.

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('cpf', 'password')}),
        ('Personal Info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_superuser', 'is_admin', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login',)}),
    )
    limited_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('cpf',)}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('cpf', 'password1', 'password2')
        }),
    )
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    change_password_form = auth_admin.AdminPasswordChangeForm
    list_display = ('cpf', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_active', 'is_admin')
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'cpf')
    ordering = ('cpf',)
    readonly_fields = ('last_login',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions')
```